# Couldn't find Post without an ID using rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

guys i am suffering from a problem from last two days and i dont know whats going wrong with my code. I have two model with the name of 'post' and 'descrip'. Descrip belongs_to post as post has_one descrip. So when i submit form for post then next form appear which is for descrip.I descrip form i have one hidden field to pass post_id. But when i submit descrip form an error appear that "POST can't be find without an id". Here below my code as
in view

```
<%= form_for :descrip, url:{action: "create", :controller => "descriptions"} do |f| %>
  <li>
    <%= f.label 'Detail' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :detail %>
  </li>
  <li>
    <%= f.hidden_field :post_id , :value => @post.id %>
  </li>
  <li>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

In Descriptions_controller

```
def new
  @descrip = Descrip.new
end

def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:descrip][:post_id])
  @descrip = @post.descrips.build(descrip_params)
  if @descrip.save
    render @post
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

model of post and descrip

```
 class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :descrip, :dependent => :destroy
 end

 class Descrip < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :post
 end
```

resources.rb

```
resources :descriptions
get "descriptions/new", :to => "descriptions#new", as: :descriptions_new
post "descriptions/create/:id", :to => "descriptions#create", as::descriptions_create

resources :posts do
  resources :descriptions
end
```

Kindly suggest me what i should do.How i can solve my error and how i can get post_id in my `decrips` table.Please.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Kingston my params are `def descrip_params
    params.require(:descrip).permit(:detail)
  end`

Comment: from `form` to controller what are all the values passing to controller.in log file you could see it.please share that one.

Comment: or in `def create` add `logger.info "---params ==> #{params.inspect}---"`,then see in log file.

Comment: inside new action of description controller. @post object is not assigned anything.

Comment: Thank u guys for reply but i am still facing problem. Ihave used binding pry but post id looks blank when i submit form. The new problem is that now error is in form on hidden field.`<%= f.hidden_field :post_id , :value => @post.id %>` at this field i get error that `undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass`. Please suggest what i should do.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are two possibilities.

1) Firstly, it could be that your params are not what you think they are and plugging in an invalid number for `Post.find()`. Could you share what your params looks like?

2) If that's not the case you could be calling id on a post that isn't yet saved and therefore can't be found by ActiveRecord within your database.  If you're submitting this form along with a form to create a post, you're likely saving the description first.  Make sure your post either exists in the database or is saved before the description to fix this.

Out of curiosity is there any reason you've made description a separate table from post? It seems like you could save yourself a lot of trouble just having it be a text column within the posts table.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Tsiege.in descrip i just pass single param which is `params.require(:descrip).permit(:detail)
`.And i submit descrip form after the post form.Form for post submit sucessfully but when i submit descrip then error occured.

Comment: You should check the params that you're getting back from the browser itself to double check it's format. Throw in a binding.pry on the line right after def create in your controller and enter ```params``` in your terminal.  The result with be series of nested hashes.  Copy and paste that into your next comment; it'll help clarify your issue for us.

Comment: Make sure ```gem 'pry'``` is in your gemfile to use pry.

Comment: Thank u guys for reply but i am still facing problem. Ihave used binding pry but post id looks blank when i submit form. The new problem is that now error is in form on hidden field.`<%= f.hidden_field :post_id , :value => @post.id %>` at this field i get error that `undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass`. Please suggest what i should do.

Comment: follow the instructions exactly as I said and paste into your response the return value of params in the binding.pry.  The other problem is that you are not passing in an instance of post from your controller to your views.  Your ```def new``` method needs ```@post = Post.new```.  But this will save that new description to a new post, not to a specific one.

Comment: I need more background on what exactly you are trying to do with this method.  ie are you making a description for a specific post or is this meant for a list of all posts with each having the ability to have a description?   I would still recommend dropping the description model and class altogether and altering your schema so that post has a text column for its description rather than making it a separate column.

Comment: can u give me ur email id so that i can send u my code for review please?

Comment: I did every action according to u guys's instructions but still hopeless. Here is output ib my browser `{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"6be0ELgSyooF/V3oWVhMSky7NueoP7xmJx9Zwe7zBQA=",
 "descrip"=>{"detail"=>"tttt",
 "post_id"=>""},
 "commit"=>"Save Descrip"}`

Comment: I am try trying that each post have its own description.Every post has its own description thats why i used descriptions a separate controller.In other words one post have one description so when i delete a post then its description must be deleted.Actually i want to render a post to some different view and description to another view. For exmaple if i add a job post then a page only display name of job lists while on click on a job descriptive page opened. I am just trying to do that.

Comment: If you put description as a column inside the posts table you could do something like ```<%= @post.description %>``` to render the description separately from the post entirely.  OR you could have a description action in the post controller that looks like this
```class PostController < ApplicationController```
```def description```
```@description = Post.find(params[:id]).description```
```end```

But it'd still be easier to simply have it be a part of the post table especially if you want every post to have one and only one description.

Answer (score 0):

in your action add `logger.info`:

```
def create
 logger.info "---params ==> #{params.inspect}---"
 @post = Post.find(params[:descrip][:post_id])
 @descrip = @post.descrips.build(descrip_params)
 if @descrip.save
  render @post
 else
 render 'new'
end
```

end

run the application then in `log/development.rb` file you can view the all `params` value.
 if params or not passing try with
     `<%= hidden_field_tag 'descrip[post_id]', @post.id  %>`

Comment: Thank u guys for reply but i am still facing problem. Ihave used binding pry but post id looks blank when i submit form. The new problem is that now error is in form on hidden field.`<%= f.hidden_field :post_id , :value => @post.id %>` at this field i get error that `undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass`. Please suggest what i should do.

Comment: @kigston i still get the error when i use your suggested hidden field text.

Comment: Now `@post` is coming `nil`,so only that error coming.check why `@post` is coming `nil`. Now `<%= f.hidden_field :post_id , :value => @post.try(:id) %>`

Comment: Thank u so much @kingston, now i have not any error on hidden field but when i submit the form then i get error in description controller which is on yhis line `@post = Post.find(params[:descrip][:post_id])`. And this line says that `Couldn't find Post without an ID`.Kindly help me please

Comment: `def new
  @descrip = Descrip.new
end` in that you are not find `@post`,please find `@post`...

Comment: `{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"AWtr2hIA9CI7rEVI5ptLALPgJcUHvAG7J2xWW9OGJZo=",
 "descrip"=>{"detail"=>"rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr",
 "post_id"=>""},
 "commit"=>"Save Descrip"}`.post_id still blank i have define in new `@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])`. Now what the hell going wrong :(

Comment: `def new` in method first find `@post`

Comment: `@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @descrip = Descrip.new`. Did u mean that?

Comment: `def new
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @descrip = Descrip.new
end`. still same error

Comment: in `new` method are you getting `post_id`?

Comment: then inspect `@post` inside the `new.html.erb`.or find `post` in console `Post.find(your id)` then find in your database whether the `post object` is there or not.

Comment: if u dont mind can i send u my code for review if u have time.

Comment: i dont know whats going wrong.I have a column in descrips table with the name post_id as posts table also have its id.

Comment: Please give me your email Id

Comment: One thing more i am also using devise. May be this may be the problem.Any idea?

Comment: first check find post in console Post.find(your post id)